# I am having trouble switching between my two AMD GPUs using Prime in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics, hybrid-graphics

Yesterday I decided to learn how to switch between my low power usage GPU and my discrete GPU in my laptop using Prime.  I started by running this command: `xrandr --listproviders`.

I got the following result:

```
Providers: number : 2
Provider 0: id: 0x75 cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 3 outputs: 3 associated providers: 1 name:AMD Radeon R6 Graphics @ pci:0000:00:01.0
Provider 1: id: 0x3f cap: 0x4, Source Offload crtcs: 0 outputs: 0 associated providers: 1 name:AMD Radeon (TM) R7 M360 @ pci:0000:03:00.0
```

I then ran this command to switch to my discrete GPU:

```
xrandr --setprovideroffloadsink 1 0
```

This resulted in the following result to my GPU with this command `DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"`:

```
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon (TM) R7 M360 (AMD ICELAND / DRM 3.18.0 / 4.13.8-041308-generic, LLVM 5.0.0)
```

Now however when I attempt to switch back to using my low powered Radeon R6 with `xrandr --setprovideroffloadsink 0 1` I get:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  34 (RRSetProviderOffloadSink)
  Value in failed request:  0x75
  Serial number of failed request:  16
  Current serial number in output stream:  17
```

I should mention I am logging into the GNOME session using Xorg on Ubuntu 17.10.  I would love to be able to switch back to my R6 so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: what you should be doing is `xrandr --setprovideroffloadsink 0 1` once, then add `DRI_PRIME=1` to the command you want to run with the second GPU. You can also choose "Launch using Dedicated Graphics Card" in the right-click menu of any app in the app list.

Answer (score 1):

I never used `--setprovideroffloadsink`. I just prepend `DRI_PRIME=1` to the program that I want to use with my dGPU. It always worked fine.

You can check your GPU usage with `radeontop` to see if it is really used. Though I have hybrid graphics with Intel+AMD. I do not know what `radeontop` shows with 2 AMD GPUs.